# Multiple github repositories smart commits to a single Jira project

Tags: github, jira, smart-commits

I'm having issues with using commits, to multiple GitHub repositories, to update a single Jira project.

This is my first attempt. at getting this setup to work. I have searched the Jira documentation but are running into problems with Atlassian moving the documentation around lately.

1. I tried deleting the connector and redo everything - same result.
2. I tried creating a new secret from GitHub and redoing the integration.
3. I checked the email are the same in both Jira and GitHub (required by Jira).

---

### I have something like the following setup

**GitHub**

- my-github/project-a
- my-github/project-b

**Jira**

- Single project with 4 letter key (eg. PROJ).
- This gives Issues in the following format; PROJ-1, PROJ-2, PROJ-475, etc.

---

### Problem

When using the Jira Issue keys in the commit message for *my-github/project-a* it works fine. Development information in Jira is updated instantly.

When using the Jira Issue keys in the commit message for *my-github/project-b* nothing happens in Jira. I can see the web hooks are sent from GitHub and are responded with a `200 OK` and contains the commit messages with the Jira Issue keys. Jira DVCS reports the repository is synced fine.

Have anyone tried a similar setup and have the magic solution? Or know of any requirements I have overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to configured **URL** as comma separated in Jira >> Project >> Details.

E.g.

```
my-github/project-a,my-github/project-b
```

Comment: I'm giving you the answer as it might have been the solution at the time. As of writing this, Jira seems to work things out if using their official integration.